# Open window from menu

Tags: swift, swift2

How can I open new window from my Xib file in Swift2? I've created new NSWindowController + xib, but I can't find how to open it?

```
@IBAction func openPreferences(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let wc = SettingsViewController()
    //...
}
```

Comment: you have to call showWindow on the new windowController. Also mind that you need to have strong reference to your windowController (if not the object will disappear at the end of method). You can have weak one if you have link from XIB (there is an option not to display window at launch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is three years old but it's at the top of a number of Google searches so I think it needs an answer that specifically addresses the original question.

Basically to get this working you need to change the code to this:

```
@IBAction func openPreferences(sender: NSMenuItem) {
    let wc = SettingsViewController(windowNibName: NSNib.Name("NameOfXib"))
    wc.showWindow(nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to use custom Storyboard instead of Xib with NSView. So here my code.

AppDelegate.swift:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    lazy var settingsController: NSWindowController? =
        NSStoryboard(name: "SettingsStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("SettingsWC")
        as? NSWindowController

    @IBAction func openPreferences(sender: NSMenuItem) {
        if let controller = settingsController { controller.showWindow(self) }
    }

}
```